# Deleting all the used pointers after each treatment

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

My idea is to get rid of all pointers I'm using in a function after each iteration.

My situation: I'm using a loop which computes millions of times some values. But after each iteration (i++), I would like to free them instead of overwriting them with the previous ones when it's about to do the same iterations, to not have some problems.

Is there a way to free all pointers I'm using in few lines?

Comment: If you use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) they will automatically be `delete`d. But do you really want to do millions of allocations in many iterations?

Comment: U can make use of an array of pointers[if they are of the same type] and den free that array using `delete[]`

Comment: @SuvP Thank you but the problem is that all the pointers that I'm having are from different types : const char, int, IplImage, double ... lots of ones!

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. In C++, we usually put our variables on the stack, so we don't need to delete them at all. When the function exits (by whatever means), they're cleaned up for us. `new` is useful if a variable must survive even after function exits, but that's clearly not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate your objects using [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) and they get released automatically.

```
for (int i(0); i < 10000000; ++i)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> pFoo(new Foo());
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> pBar(new Bar(pFoo.get()));

    pBar->DoSomething();
}
```

When leaving the scope of the loop the `std::unique_ptr`-object's are getting destroyed automatically, since they are allocated on the stack. Their destructor calls `delete` on the object they manage.